# R Formula that only uses a subset of a factor

Tags: r, categorical-data

What is the least painful way to do the following in R? We want to run a model with a formula like this:

```
Model #1:  Speed ~ male + female
```

Unfortunately, our data frame has just a single column, `Gender`, which has levels `'female'`, `'male'`, and `'unknown'`. We could then write a formula like this:

```
Model #2:  Speed ~ Gender
```

However, we don't want to treat `'unknown'` as its own gender value. We want the model's semantics to be such that the `'unknown'` rows will comprise the baseline for the model, and then the effects of the `'male'` and `'female'` variables will go on top of that. We do NOT want to simply select a subset of rows that are either `'female'` or `'male'` and run model #2; we need to include the `'unknown'` levels as  baseline. How can this be done?

(I understand rearranging the data frame would allow for running model #1. Assume for the moment that this is not feasible.)

Thanks!

Comment: The first formulation suggests your data have both "male" and "female" attributes and that individuals can be both or neither of those! The second one does *exactly* what you ask (provided "unknown" has been made the base level of the `Gender` factor). I wonder therefore whether you are accurately communicating your question. Could you perhaps tell us in words what these models mean to you?

Comment: I don't know how to reconcile "we don't want to treat `'unknown'` as its own gender value" and "we need to include the `'unknown'` levels as baseline" comments. If the `'unknown'`s are included, how can they be included but as their own category?

Comment: Question really not clear, but perhaps you need to do Gender <- relevel(Gender, ref="unknown")

Comment: It's now obvious R isn't my native programming language! I rarely ever use it, and so didn't realize that factors have a baseline/reference level. This reference/releveling is exactly what was necessary. Thanks!

Comment: You can also change the reference level without modyfing the factor: type lm(speed ~ C(gender, base=2), data=mydata) and then the reference level is the second level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, you'll want to use the following code:

```
data$gender <- factor(data$gender, levels=c('unknown','male','female')
```

and then fit your model. I'll use a basic linear model here as an example.

```
linearmod <- lm(speed~gender, data=yourdata, ...)
```

would fit a model of the form $\hat{y}=\beta_0+\beta_1*male+\beta_2*female$ where $male$ and $female$ are Boolean variables that only take on a value of 0 or 1. So in the case of 'unknown', both $male$ and $female$ would be 0, making $\beta_0$ the predicted value ($\hat{y}$) of the speed of a person with unknown gender. Similarly, the predicted speed of a person known to be male would be $\beta_0 +\beta_1$.
The purpose of the `factor()` command is to order the levels the way you want (with unknown as the baseline) instead of alphabetically, which is the default. Setting the base level to 'unknown' doesn't actually change the model that will be fit by the call to `lm()`, but it makes the output optimal for comparing 'male' to 'unknown' and 'female' to 'unknown'. Alternatively you could use the `relevel()` function to rearrange the base level of your factor variable.